# Span spacing interferes with text rendering

Tags: css

I am writing an autocomplete, and the text input by the user splits each matching item in the list into two differently coloured parts: the head and the tail.

I have made the head and tail as two adjacent `span` elements like this:

```
<span class='head'></span>Hello<span class='tail'>, World!</span>
```

This works well unless there is a capital letter at the end of the head and a lowercase letter at the start of the tail. Like so:

No head `<span class='head'></span><span class='tail'>TestProductionClient</span>`

[image: No head]

Single capital letter in the head `<span class='head'>T</span>`

[image: Single letter]

Normal again between two lowercase letters

[image: Normal again]

As you can see, there is an extra spacing between the letters "T" and "e" in the second picture. Is there a way to solve this by changing this gap between spans, or more generally, is there a way to colour parts of words without affecting the rendering of the word?

Comment: If think this is a special case, but you can add a negative `margin-right` of few pixel on your first span, but it's not good. **l** and **i** can be override.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or codepen (or similar) to demonstrate? Also, what browsers are affected? Is there any css applied to the `.head` element?

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the effect showing. https://jsfiddle.net/1gxkd6fp/
I have tried this on all major browsers.

Comment: @hungerstar the code does the equivalent of `$('.head').html(first_half)`, etc. It is the same when I simply type out the html manually.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're dealing with the font kerning algorithm.

Here's a potentially simpler way:

```css
::first-letter { 
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: -.05em; /* careful with this; should be tested with various 
                               letter and font combinations */
}

span { font-size: 2em; }
```

```html
<span>TestProductionClient</span>
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning

Answer (score 0):

On your font, `T` and `e` are rendered together with a special kerning. Because there is space for the `T` to move closer to the `e`, and this looks more natural, the makers moved them together. However, when `T` and `e` are not directly after each other, in the same text node, the letters are showed with the default distance, and the spacing seems unnatural (which is why they did it in the first place).

Relevant part of code: (lines 3353-3355 from Arial svg file downloaded [here](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/17d05f87d359cc4e0e6bd20684d48a11))

```
...
<hkern u1="T" u2="i" k="76" />
<hkern u1="T" u2="e" k="227" />
<hkern u1="T" u2="c" k="227" />
...
```

> The ‘hkern’ and ‘vkern’ elements define kerning pairs for horizontally-oriented and vertically-oriented pairs of glyphs, respectively.
>   <sub>[source](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#KernElements)</sub>

## Edit

It was **not** a ligature; I was wrong there. It is special kerning. Sorry for confusion. The idea remains the same; it's a feature of the font that doesn't work in the way that (and it shouldn't).

Comment: I suspected something like this. Thanks for the info. In this case, is there any way to colour only part of a word? independently of font?

Comment: Not a ligature, just kerning. This would be a ligature: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Ligature_fi.svg/2000px-Ligature_fi.svg.png

Comment: @Tobl I noticed, and I found the relevant part in the Arial source code. I'll edit in a minute.